# "cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-parameter" Error

Tags: c++, build, compilation

I've been trying to build a file in QtCreator (With MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit on a Windows 8 64-bit machine) but I've been getting the following error:

**cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-parameter**

I don't have much experience with this, so I have no clue as to how to solve it and would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["1>cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wno-deprecated'" Erro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717551/1cl-command-line-error-d8021-invalid-numeric-argument-wno-deprecated-er)

Comment: If above post doesn't help then problem could be "invalid numeric argument" as mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfk5bs0s.aspx

Comment: The problem wasn't the same as that, but thanks anyway. The error had something to do with Boost and the .pro required a unix* in front of the line causing the errors. So it's all fixed and running now.

Comment: Coudl you post and accept an answer giving more details of how to fix this problem? It would be of help to thers