# CMake configuration fails on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, cmake

CMake used to work for me on Windows' Visual C++ Toolchain. But recently, I have problems with CMake running even the configuration. CMake fails with the following errors. I'm using this inside the Windows developer prompt.

How can I solve this problem inside the developer prompt? I'm not running this inside the Visual Studio IDE.

```
PS C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\master thesis\uml data\yuml\parser\simple_wc_example\build> cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19041.
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29335.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):     
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
```

Is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Users/Song/Documents/UDEM/master thesis/uml data/yuml/parser/simple_wc_example/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_a342f.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.2+25e4d540b for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29335 for x64
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  cl /c /I"C:\src\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\msbuild\..\..\..\installed\x64-windows\include" /Zi /Wall /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS 
/fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_a342f.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_a342f.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue  -Wno-deprecated-register "C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\master thesis\uml data\yuml\parser\simple_wc_example\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx"   
    cl : command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wno-deprecated-register' [C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\master thesis\uml data\yuml\parser\simple_wc_example\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_a342f.vcxproj]

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Song/Documents/UDEM/master thesis/uml data/yuml/parser/simple_wc_example/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Song/Documents/UDEM/master thesis/uml data/yuml/parser/simple_wc_example/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Looks like a clang option is being used for msvc

Comment: The problem is that your compiler (Microsoft "cl") doesn't understand one of the compile flags in your build environment ("/Wno-deprecated-register").  The solution is to simply remove that option:  ["cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wno-deprecated'" Erro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717551/1cl-command-line-error-d8021-invalid-numeric-argument-wno-deprecated-er)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The link is for a GUI based compiling system, I believe Visual Studio. How do you remove the option received by 'cl' via the command line?

Comment: Maybe you set an environment variable. Maybe this project forces the wrong compiler settings in the CMakeLists.txt. You may want to search your project directory for the following text: `-Wno-deprecated-register`

Comment: Is there a way to find out the value of the variables taken by the compiler?