# cmake with cl: invalid numeric argument '/Wno-uninitialized'

Tags: c++, cmake, itk

The closest I could find was [cmake invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274006/cmake-invalid-numeric-argument-wextra) but I don't know where to add proposed text to CMakeLists.txt...

I'm building ITK 4.5.1 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine, using MSVC 2010.

When configuring, I get the following error. Thank you for any hint.

```
1> Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 10.0.40219.1.

1>------ Build started: Project: cmTryCompileExec91952967, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

1>Build started 17/02/2014 16:26:13.

1>PrepareForBuild:

1>  Creating directory "C:\ITK\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

1>InitializeBuildStatus:

1>  Creating "cmTryCompileExec91952967.dir\Debug\cmTryCompileExec91952967.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

1>ClCompile:

1>  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64

1>  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-uninitialized" /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTryCompileExec91952967.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec91952967.dir\Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:prompt src.c  -Wno-uninitialized 

1>cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wno-uninitialized'
```

Comment: It looks a bit like you are trying to pass gcc parameters to the msvc compiler...

Comment: This part looks suspicious too: `/D "C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-uninitialized"`.  At a guess, `C_HAS_WARNING-Wno-uninitialized` looks like a CMake variable which should be getting dereferenced inside a generator expression or `if` block.  Probably showing us your CMakeLists.txt would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sources zip file was not correctly unzipped, so I had missing files, and the corresponding error was visible only on CMake-GUI interface, not in log file.

Once fixed, everything went smoothly.

Comment: Since you fixed the problem on your own, you can mark your own answer as the correct one. :-)

Comment: Sure but I have 48 hours delay due to reputation, still have to wait one hour :-)