# Caffe2: Couldn't determine version from header: Change Dir:

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, conda

I am trying to run facebook's hanabi repository but I ran into problem.

I followed the guide lines in this link: https://github.com/facebookresearch/hanabi_SAD

I ran these insructions:

```
# create new conda env
conda create -n hanabi python=3.7
conda activate hanabi

# install pytorch
pip install torch==1.8.1+cu101 torchvision==0.9.1+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

# install other dependencies
pip install numpy
pip install psutil

# if the current cmake version is < 3.15
conda install -c conda-forge cmake
```

then I couldnt find the `.bashsh` file (I have windows) so I skipped this:

```
# set path
CONDA_PREFIX=${CONDA_PREFIX:-"$(dirname $(which conda))/../"}
export CPATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/include:${CPATH}
export LIBRARY_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib:${LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

# avoid tensor operation using all cpu cores
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

and then I ran this:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/facebookresearch/hanabi.git

cd hanabi
mkdir build
cd build
```

but when I tried to run this command:

```
cmake ..
```

I recieved an error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/dorco/miniconda3/envs/hanabi/Lib/site- 
packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/cuda.cmake:74 (message):
Caffe2: Couldn't determine version from header: Change Dir:
C:/Users/dorco/anaconda3/Codes/hanabi_SAD-master/build/qPlKM/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp




Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_9ad3a.vcxproj
/p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m &&
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+5e4b48a27 for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29914 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
cl /c /I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\include" /Zi /Wall /WX- 
/diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- 
/EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR 
/Fo"cmTC_9ad3a.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_9ad3a.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue  
-O3 -Wextra -Wno-register -fPIC -march=native -Wfatal-errors -O3 -Wextra -Wno-register - 
fPIC -march=native -Wfatal-errors "C:\Users\dorco\anaconda3\Codes\hanabi_SAD- 
master\build\detect_cuda_version.cc"

cl : command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wextra'
[C:\Users\dorco\anaconda3\Codes\hanabi_SAD- 
master\build\qPlKM\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_9ad3a.vcxproj]
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

```
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Users/dorco/miniconda3/envs/hanabi/Lib/site- 
packages/torch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:88 (include)
C:/Users/dorco/miniconda3/envs/hanabi/Lib/site- 
packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:68 (find_package)
rela/CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
```

Comment: You have cloned some linux/gcc configuration. That's a gcc option. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274040/681865 for some ideas

Comment: I tried to add this: 
# Set default compile flags for GCC
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    message(STATUS "GCC detected, adding compile flags")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra")
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

   to CMakeLists.txt but nothing was happed, I still got the same error. Any help?

Comment: Not from me, sorry. You might want to raise a bug at their tracker on Github and see if someone can help you